# “Sorry this site hasn't been shared with you” root domain

Tags: permissions

When I try to browse `http://foo/` it gives the

> Sorry this site hasn't been shared with you

error but when I try to `http://foo/pages/main.aspx` (homepage) works just fine.

How can I solve this problem?

```
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA898  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/)). Parent No  
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA898  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra/)  2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA898  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7u   Medium      Mapping URI from 'http://tointra:80/' to 'http://TOINTRA/'  2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x5B54  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)). Parent No   
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x5B54  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)   2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x5B54  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=False, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0  2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x5B54  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,2 agb9s    2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.46  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x5B54  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)). Execution Time=3.80782473887198 2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.47  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA898  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 adc7u    2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.47  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA898  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/)). Execution Time=10.3477802262587    2445219d-ca19-0031-8dee-1b847d06b115
08/06/2015 11:34:10.49  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x9148  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/)). Parent No  
08/06/2015 11:34:10.49  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x9148  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra/)  2445219d-2a1c-0031-8dee-1b2d21c08ea8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.49  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x9148  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7u   Medium      Mapping URI from 'http://tointra:80/' to 'http://TOINTRA/'  2445219d-2a1c-0031-8dee-1b2d21c08ea8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.50  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x67A4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)). Parent No   
08/06/2015 11:34:10.50  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x67A4  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)   2445219d-2a1c-0031-8dee-1b2d21c08ea8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.50  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x67A4  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq    2445219d-2a1c-0031-8dee-1b2d21c08ea8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.50  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x67A4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)). Execution Time=1.52994922350402 2445219d-2a1c-0031-8dee-1b2d21c08ea8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.50  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x9148  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 adc7u    2445219d-2a1c-0031-8dee-1b2d21c08ea8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.50  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x9148  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/)). Execution Time=5.92181640499329    2445219d-2a1c-0031-8dee-1b2d21c08ea8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.52  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x3E18  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/)). Parent No  
08/06/2015 11:34:10.52  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x3E18  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra/)  2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.52  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x3E18  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7u   Medium      Mapping URI from 'http://tointra:80/' to 'http://TOINTRA/'  2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.52  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA57C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)). Parent No   
08/06/2015 11:34:10.52  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA57C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)   2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.54  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA57C  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|XXX\intrauser, ClaimsCount=24    2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.54  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA57C  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,18 agb9s   2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.54  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA57C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/)). Execution Time=19.6523132645278 2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.54  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xA57C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.55  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x3E18  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7v   Medium      Reverse mapping URI from 'http://tointra/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftointra' to 'http://tointra/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftointra'   2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.55  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x3E18  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,0 adc7u,27 adc7v   2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.55  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x3E18  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/)). Execution Time=29.790564139904 2445219d-9a1d-0031-8dee-196a02c6fb81
08/06/2015 11:34:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xC620  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://tointra)). Parent No   
08/06/2015 11:34:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xC620  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://tointra)   2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xC620  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7u   Medium      Mapping URI from 'http://tointra:80/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftointra' to 'http://TOINTRA/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftointra'    2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x1064  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftointra)). Parent No  
08/06/2015 11:34:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x1064  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://tointra:80/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftointra)  2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x1064  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|XXX\intrauser, ClaimsCount=24    2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x1064  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.62  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x1064  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,3 agb9s    2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.62  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x1064  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra:80/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftointra)). Execution Time=40.9539139917761    2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.62  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xC620  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 adc7u    2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:10.62  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0xC620  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://tointra/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://tointra)). Execution Time=45.5311129088228 2445219d-5a21-0031-8dee-1933b9e827f8
08/06/2015 11:34:11.62  w3wp.exe (0x29C0)                           0x6788  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           ac3iq   High        Ims::EndPoints: old: net.tcp://TOINTRA/3B6BC9/QueryProcessingComponent1/ImsQueryInternal;, new: net.tcp://TOINTRA/3B6BC9/QueryProcessingComponent1/ImsQueryInternal;     
08/06/2015 11:34:11.99  w3wp.exe (0x3020)                           0x0D40  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)
```

Comment: On which site collection template or site template is based that site? Could you additionally enumerate the standards features active. `C:\PS>Get-SPSite http://somesite | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL |%{ Get-SPFeature -Web $_ } | Select DisplayName,ID -Unique`

Comment: What happen if you set main.aspx as homepage?

Answer (score 2):

## Set the default page in SharePoint

You can set the page as your home page.  There should be an option in the ribbon for this when at the page in question. Publishing features need to be enabled for this option to appear.

Alternatively, you could check site settings.  In look and feel you should be able to set a welcome page.

You can also set this in sharepoint designer, or programmatically.

Check these links :)

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/09/05/how-to-set-a-page-as-home-page-in-sharepoint-2013-site/

## Check your Default document settings in IIS

Open IIS on the web front end and find your website in the list of sites.
Select the default documents page and add main.aspx to the list.

Alternatively, try renaming main.aspx to Default.aspx in the pages library on SharePoint.

Here is a link for this :

http://www.serverintellect.com/support/windowsserver/default-document-iis7/

## Check Alternate Access Mappings, Host Header, and Bindings!

Firstly, you will want to check your Alternate Access Mappings in SharePoint.

Secondly, and importantly, you want to also check your Host Header is correctly configured in SharePoint and IIS.

Finally, in IIS check all bindings are all correct on every server.

Here are some great articles on all of these things! :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx

http://thuansoldier.net/?p=1323

http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2010/06/making-a-sharepoint-2010-site-externally-available-alternate-access-mappings-host-header-bindings.html

## Don't worry, it is a common misconfiguration!

One great article I have just come across now lists this as a common misconfiguration. Check out number #4 in its list! :)

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2010/top-10-sharepoint-2010-configuration-mistakes-and-how-fix-them

## Check your DNS and point SharePoint to itself

Make sure you have configured your DNS records on your local DNS server.

Also, edit your HOSTS file and input the names of that machines in the farm and their IP addresses. This will save your network from too many DNS requests.

This it more Network level stuff than Application configuration, but if you haven't set a DNS record (or HOSTS file record) somewhere, you will have problems!

http://blog.walisystemsinc.com/2012/11/sharepoint-2013-setup-multiple-urls-in.html

http://www.fpweb.net/tutorials/hosting-basics/edit-hostfile/

## Do you need to disable the loopback check?

If you have a single machine farm, and you host SharePoint and SQL on one machine, you may need to disable a Windows Security feature that stops certain traffic designated for itself.

Read more here :

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

## Final Thought

If you have SSL enabled and you are accessing the site via HTTPS, make sure you have installed the SSL Certificates on all of the IIS servers and that all of the certificates are all valid. This probably doesn't apply to you, but I put it here for anybody else who ends up here with a similar problem. Similarly, if you are using multiple SSL Certificates for different domain names hosted (or load balanced) from 1 IP address, make sure you have set up SNI correctly in IIS (IIS 8 and above).

Comment: Its already homepage and welcome page.

Comment: Ah sorry.   Have you configured alternate access mappings?

Comment: there are 3 urls in here; http://foo, http://foo:38599 (SharePoint Central Administration), http://foo:90

Comment: What kind of site is it? publishing?

Comment: yes Its publishing

Comment: Have you ran a ULS trace and hit the site at http://foo/ ?

Comment: I just added log files to question.

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it helps.

It covers checking different aspects of the configuration.


I think it is just a config problem.

Let me know how you get on! :)

Comment: Did you ever sort out the issue?

Comment: I gave this subject to better qualified developers on sharepoint, I think they are still investigating. I will let you know If I can hear a solution from them. thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Almost all (if not all) of the links are dead.